# Repetition of gridview elements.....!

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview, android-gridview

The code is working but the problem is that, that certain elements are repeating in the text view and some are left out. For example "Who we are" is displayed twice. Also I couldn't center textview elements. I have posted the screenshot of it. I am new in android programming so help me out, anyone.

This is the Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GridView grid;
    public WebView webView;
    public int pos;

    String[] desc = { "Who We Are", "What We Do", "Entrepreneur", "Scholarship", "Admission",
            "Internship", "Industrial Visit", "Project", "Buy or Sell Projects", "Free Training", "College Registration",
            "Information", "Feedback", "Contact"    };


    int[] imageId = { R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy,
            R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy,
            R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy,
            R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy,
            R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy 

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

        GridDesign adapter = new GridDesign(MainActivity.this, desc, imageId);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                pos = position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, webView.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

This is the custom grid view class.

```
public class GridDesign extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] desc;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public GridDesign(Context c, String[] web, int[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.desc = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return desc.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_element, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(desc[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

This is main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is single grid element layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/im" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="23"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getView` method doesn't reset the contents of your `View` if `convertView` is not `null`.  If `convertView` is not `null`, you need to set the contents otherwise it will retain the old contents from the old view, and you'll see duplicated data. If `convertView` is not `null` it means you are reusing a view that has scrolled off the screen (this makes scrolling smoother as you don't have to have the views reallocated and deallocated as you scroll. Therefore, it's this reusing that means you'll see some repetition of the elements and some elements missing because in your `getView` method you haven't reset the contents when the view is being reused.

To fix this, you can move your code that sets the view contents outside your `if` statement so you do something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_element, parent, false);
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
    textView.setText(desc[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
    return grid;
}
```

Comment: A little help with the alignment of textview alignment inside grid element would do wonders for me.

Comment: As your `LinearLayout` is `vertical`, I'm assuming you want the `TextView` centred below the image? If so, you just need to set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` on the `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the reuse of the recycled view, you may be getting the views already initalized from before. You can initialize the view each time, rewriting the code like this:

```
        if (convertView == null) {

        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_element, parent, false);
        } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        textView.setText(desc[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
```

or better yet, adopt ViewHolder pattern ([View Holder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)).